# In web forms, can you use .PostBackUrl without javascript?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

So, we have a web forms page that we need to post to another page and so we're using `Button.PostBackUrl`. However, it seems that this requires javascript to be enabled in the browser.

Does it need javascript to be enabled in the browser? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does need JavaScript, because when the button is clicked the action of the form is dynamically changed before the form is submitted.

It's not always obvious what ASP.NET functionality is JavaScript-dependent. Even the innocent little ol' LinkButton is useless when JavaScript is disabled.

There are alternatives to PostBackUrl. You could use a traditional Button and then do a Response.Redirect or Server.Transer to the new page?

Comment: Is there no way around that? Or are we going to have to change this in another way?